# How to for loop list all values into a dataframe? Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, dataframe, format

I have a dataframe that I'm trying to modify.
I also have three lists that can reference each part of the dataframe in order to perform calculations.

```
signal
['signal0', 'signal1']
df_list
['A', 'B']
df_ma2_list
['A_MA', 'B_MA']
```

My dataframe is fine up to this point:

```
        A_MA    B_MA    A   B   signal0 signal1
      0 NaN      NaN    50  55     0      0
      1 NaN      NaN    55  67     0      0
      2 65.00   70.33   90  89     0      0
      3 54.67   63.33   19  34     0      0
      4 64.00   68.33   83  82     0      0
      5 64.33   70.33   91  95     0      0
      6 81.33   91.33   70  97     0      0
      7 86.33   95.00   98  93     0      0
      8 83.33   98.33   82  105    0      0
      9 86.67   102.67  80  110    0      0
```

I can do a manual calculation for both columns A with A_MA and B with B_MA in order to generate signals of 1 or -1 like this:

```
 df2.loc[df2.A > df2.A_MA, "signal0"] = -1
 df2.loc[df2.A < df2.A_MA, "signal0"] = 1

 df2.loc[df2.B > df2.B_MA, "signal1"] = -1
 df2.loc[df2.B < df2.B_MA, "signal1"] = 1
 round(df2,1)
```

I get the correct output where signal0 and signal1 are for both A with A_MA and B with B_MA, respectively.
So, for instance, in row 7, B = 105 and B_MA =98, so signal1 = -1.
Also in row 7, A= 82 and A_MA = 83, so signal0 = 1.

```
            A_MA    B_MA    A   B   signal0 signal1
          0 NaN      NaN    50  55    -1    -1
          1 NaN      NaN    55  67    -1    -1
          2 65.0     70.3   90  89     1     1
          3 54.7     63.3   19  34    -1    -1
          4 64.0     68.3   83  82     1     1
          5 64.3     70.3   91  95     1     1
          6 81.3     91.3   70  97    -1     1
          7 86.3     95.0   98  93     1    -1
          8 83.3    98.3    82  105   -1     1
          9 86.7    102.7   80  110   -1     1
```

The above method is too long for bigger dataframes. 
So I want to use a for loop of the three lists I have to calculate the dataframe automatically regardless of how many columns. So if I had columns A to Z, and A_MA - Z_MA, and signal0 to signal26. It would calculate all of the signals based solely on the three ticker lists which are df_list, df_ma2_list and signal.
I used this equation, but it only gives me the same signal for B with B_MB in both signal0 an signal1 columns.

```
   for i in signal:
      for x in df_list:
            for f in df_ma2_list:

                df2.loc[df2["{}".format(x)] > df2["{}".format(f)],  "{}".format(i)] = -1                   
                df2.loc[df2["{}".format(x)] < df2["{}".format(f)], "{}".format(i)] = 1

            A_MA    B_MA    A   B   signal0 signal1
          0 NaN      NaN    50  55     0      0
          1 NaN      NaN    55  67     0      0
          2 65.00   70.33   90  89    -1     -1
          3 54.67   63.33   19  34     1      1
          4 64.00   68.33   83  82    -1     -1
          5 64.33   70.33   91  95    -1     -1
          6 81.33   91.33   70  97    -1     -1
          7 86.33   95.00   98  93     1      1
          8 83.33   98.33   82  105   -1     -1
          9 86.67   102.67  80  110   -1     -1
```

Also, using np.where unfortunately generates the same dataframe problem with both signal columns having the same values.

```
 import numpy as np

 for f in signal:
     for i in df_list:
        for x in df_ma_list:

             df3["{}".format(f)] = np.where((df3["{}".format(i)] > df3["{}".format(x)]), 1, -1)   
             df3["{}".format(f)] = np.where((df3["{}".format(i)] > df3["{}".format(x)]), 1, -1)
```

df3

I need to get the correct signals for both columns using the code above with a for loop of the three lists. If there is a better way of doing this please let me know. Sorry for the long question! Many thanks.

Comment: Perhaps look into [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I already tried np.where and it gave me the same problem.

Comment: You're getting the same signal for B and B_MB because you're not tying A to just A_MA and B to just B_MA. Look a little bit more deeply at your for loop; you're comparing A's to B's...

Comment: Wow, thank you! Was running out of hope. I see that you used only one for loop for all the lists; ts, ma, and signal. That makes sense. I've only started Python about 2-3 months ago for my dissertation in financial mathematics. Big relief. Thanks again not_a_robot!

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept the answer by hitting the checkmark next to the votes, if you're satisfied :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import string
```

Let's create some data:

```
>>> data = {letter: np.random.randn(100000) for letter in string.ascii_uppercase}
>>> data.update({letter + '_MA': np.random.randn(100000) for letter in string.ascii_uppercase})
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data)
>>> df.head()
          A      A_MA         B      B_MA         C      C_MA         D  \
0  0.194264  1.026269 -0.754151 -0.156895  1.583709 -0.018520  0.895973   
1 -0.105569 -0.380830 -1.464730 -2.057322 -0.448863 -0.270909 -1.011525   
2  1.306095  0.003583 -0.714843  0.132892 -0.162723  0.494365 -0.702625   
3  0.194403 -0.828941  0.472967  1.218849 -0.092833  1.639822 -1.953157   
4 -0.680198  0.078923  0.939365 -0.267072  0.275587  2.262286 -0.196426   

       D_MA         E      E_MA    ...            V      V_MA         W  \
0 -0.185024  0.803631 -0.415856    ...    -0.042800  0.439730 -0.197314   
1 -0.784399 -0.758771  0.531884    ...    -0.560350  0.588178  0.527035   
2  0.476952 -0.160694  1.397329    ...    -0.889000  0.667174  0.578487   
3  1.755312 -0.191594 -0.701020    ...     1.092291  0.711403  0.726068   
4  0.195957  1.222551  1.071865    ...    -0.869672 -0.315218 -1.400713   

       W_MA         X      X_MA         Y      Y_MA         Z      Z_MA  
0 -0.942320 -1.918997  1.792692 -1.656744  0.739270 -2.486536 -0.289948  
1  2.065264 -1.257320 -1.636223  0.910484 -0.771143  2.084536  0.413396  
2 -1.049890  1.888866 -1.658292 -0.494236  0.980870  1.139787  1.085633  
3 -1.144944  0.314362 -0.183625  0.148545 -0.214450 -0.992381  1.300748  
4 -1.220797  1.049443  1.171045 -0.403457  0.868933  1.985064 -0.842899  

[5 rows x 52 columns]
```

Next, we'll pair up each letter with its appropriate moving average (MA) and signal column:

```
>>> columns = [(letter, letter + '_MA', 'signal' + str(ord(letter)-65)) for letter in string.ascii_uppercase]
>>> columns
[('A', 'A_MA', 'signal0'), ('B', 'B_MA', 'signal1'), ('C', 'C_MA', 'signal2'), ('D', 'D_MA', 'signal3'), ('E', 'E_MA', 'signal4'), ('F', 'F_MA', 'signal5'), ('G', 'G_MA', 'signal6'), ('H', 'H_MA', 'signal7'), ('I', 'I_MA', 'signal8'), ('J', 'J_MA', 'signal9'), ('K', 'K_MA', 'signal10'), ('L', 'L_MA', 'signal11'), ('M', 'M_MA', 'signal12'), ('N', 'N_MA', 'signal13'), ('O', 'O_MA', 'signal14'), ('P', 'P_MA', 'signal15'), ('Q', 'Q_MA', 'signal16'), ('R', 'R_MA', 'signal17'), ('S', 'S_MA', 'signal18'), ('T', 'T_MA', 'signal19'), ('U', 'U_MA', 'signal20'), ('V', 'V_MA', 'signal21'), ('W', 'W_MA', 'signal22'), ('X', 'X_MA', 'signal23'), ('Y', 'Y_MA', 'signal24'), ('Z', 'Z_MA', 'signal25')]
```

For each regular time-series, its moving average, and the corresponding `signal` column, if the regular time-series is greater than the moving average, assign a -1, otherwise assign 1.

```
>>> for ts, ma, signal in columns:
...     df[signal] = np.where(df[ts] > df[ma], -1, 1)
... 
>>> df.head()
          A      A_MA         B      B_MA         C      C_MA         D  \
0  0.194264  1.026269 -0.754151 -0.156895  1.583709 -0.018520  0.895973   
1 -0.105569 -0.380830 -1.464730 -2.057322 -0.448863 -0.270909 -1.011525   
2  1.306095  0.003583 -0.714843  0.132892 -0.162723  0.494365 -0.702625   
3  0.194403 -0.828941  0.472967  1.218849 -0.092833  1.639822 -1.953157   
4 -0.680198  0.078923  0.939365 -0.267072  0.275587  2.262286 -0.196426   

       D_MA         E      E_MA    ...     signal16  signal17  signal18  \
0 -0.185024  0.803631 -0.415856    ...           -1         1        -1   
1 -0.784399 -0.758771  0.531884    ...            1         1        -1   
2  0.476952 -0.160694  1.397329    ...           -1         1        -1   
3  1.755312 -0.191594 -0.701020    ...            1         1        -1   
4  0.195957  1.222551  1.071865    ...            1        -1         1   

   signal19  signal20  signal21  signal22  signal23  signal24  signal25  
0        -1        -1         1        -1         1         1         1  
1         1         1         1         1        -1        -1        -1  
2        -1        -1         1        -1        -1         1        -1  
3        -1        -1        -1        -1        -1        -1         1  
4         1        -1         1         1         1         1        -1  

[5 rows x 78 columns]
```

Here's a closer look:

```
>>> df[list(columns[0]) + list(columns[1])].head()
          A      A_MA  signal0         B      B_MA  signal1
0  0.194264  1.026269        1 -0.754151 -0.156895        1
1 -0.105569 -0.380830       -1 -1.464730 -2.057322       -1
2  1.306095  0.003583       -1 -0.714843  0.132892        1
3  0.194403 -0.828941       -1  0.472967  1.218849        1
4 -0.680198  0.078923        1  0.939365 -0.267072       -1
```

You'll have to decide exactly what you want to do in the case, for example, of `A` being equal to `A_MA` for a given row (in your approach, just using `>` and `<` with no `<=` or `>=` leaves out potential rows with equality.

Answer (score 0):

For lists use zip like the following:

```
   zip_list = list(zip(df_list, df_ma2_list, signal))
```

This gives the following:

```
   zip_list

   [('A', 'A_MA', 'signal0'), ('B', 'B_MA', 'signal1'), ('C', 'C_MA', 'signal2')]
```

The zip_list can then be used for a single for loop as follows:

```
        for df_list, df_ma2_list, signal in zip_list:
              df[signal] = np.where(df[df_list] > df[df_ma2_list], -1, 1)
```

​
Hope that helps anyone who might be a bit confused. Thanks again to not_a_robot :)